# How do ldap search for email address in contacts' 2nd/3rd alternate email addresses?

Tags: ldap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ldap-query

I have an LDAP server with my email contacts so that I can lookup contacts by name/email, etc. However, it only seems to search and find the first email address for any contact.

For example, if I have a person:

```
LastName: Doe
FirstName: John
Email: jdoe@work.com
Email2: johndoe@home.com
Email3: johndoe@fun.com
```

It only searches through or returns the first email. For example, if I search for "John", it will return only the "jdoe@work.com" even though the other two email addresses have "john" in them. The search filters I've tried are:

```
//This one will both look through and match the first email but ignores the 2nd/3rd
(|(displayName=*%v*)(mail=*%v*)(uid=*%v*)(givenname=*%v*)(sn=*%v*)(cn=*%v*))

//This one throws an error saying "mail2" and "mail3" are invalid filters.
(|(displayName=*%v*)(mail=*%v*)(mail2=*%v*)(mail3=*%v*)(uid=*%v*)(givenname=*%v*)(sn=*%v*)(cn=*%v*))
```

What should I be using?

Also, does anyone have a link to some page that lists all the possible filters I can put in an ldap person search?

Comment: See this [article](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/) for a discussion of the LDAP search request, including filters.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange does not store additional mailaddresses in fields like mail2 or mail3. All addresses are stored in the multi-valued field "proxyAddresses". This field contains one line for each address in the form of

address-type:address

Example:

smtp:test@contoso.local
SMTP:user@contoso.local

The second entry in the example would be main address for that account, because the SMTP prefix is all uppercase.

So you would search for (proxyAddress=*%v*) or something like that. I don't know the LDAP search syntax out of my head.

**Edit**: Another option is to use the ResolveNames operation of the EWS webservices (see http://www.infinitec.de/post/2009/04/13/Resolving-the-primary-email-address-with-Exchange-WebServices-ResolveNames-operation.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563518(v=exchg.140).aspx).

Comment: I tried adding `(proxyAddress=*%v*)` and `(proxyAddresses=*%v*)` and the other two emails still won't show up (and it still doesn't search those fields)! :( But I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Try (proxyAddresses=smtp:*%v*).

Comment: Unfortunately, `(proxyAddresses=smtp:*%v*)` also doesn't work.

Comment: While I was finally able to get it to search the second and 3rd email ((smtpemail2=*%v*)(smtpemail3=*%v*)) it still only returns the first email, despite finding it via the second or third! Any idea how to make it return all three?

Comment: @Don Rhummy what do you mean by 'it still only returns the first email'. It should return the entire entry, including all the values of all the attributes, unless you're only requesting specific attributes, in which case it will give you those.

Comment: @EJP: Well, he tagged his question with Exchange and ExchangeWebServices.

Answer (score 1):

The filter:

```
(|(displayName=*%v*)(mail=*%v*)(uid=*%v*)(givenname=*%v*)(sn=*%v*)(cn=*%v*))
```

will not match the entry:

```
LastName: Doe
FirstName: John
Email: jdoe@work.com
Email2: johndoe@home.com
Email3: johndoe@fun.com
```

because none of the filter assertions match any of the attribute names in the given entry.

```
(|(Email=jd*)(Email2=john*)(Email3=john*)(lastName=Do*))
```

would match. Have you considered using the standard names for the example entry you give?

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear. "Email," "Email1," etc are "friendly names" for those fields. In ldap queries, it doesn't matter what an ldap server calls it, "mail" will search for the primary email address.

Comment: @DonThummy Of course it matters. LDAP attributes have names, and aliases, and you have to use a name or alias that the server understands. You seem to think that LDAP filters have some magical properties like name-rewriting. They don't.

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory was released with some schema choices that are questionable. Now it is hard to fix them.

One of those is that mail, was flagged as single valued. This should have been a multivalued attribute. Thus the use of proxyAddresses, where it tries to overload a string syntax attribute with more information by using smtp: or x500: or SIP: to indicate a protocol for the address. Then upper case (SMTP) means primary and lower case (smtp) means secondary.

This also occured for telephoneNumber being single valued, and extra values now overflow into the attribute otherPhone.

Same for:

- facsimileTelephoneNumber and otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber
- labelledUri and url
- homePhone and otherHomePhone
- pager and otherPager
- mobile and otherMobile